# Fetch partial results from a JSON

Tags: json, fetch

I'm interested in some sort of pagination that I can apply when fetching my data, not only when rendering it. 
Basically, I am using an external Github API(a JSON file) which returns an array with a few thousand records.

I would like to make a fetch request and get back only the first 100, then the next 100, and so on, depending if the user scrolls lower on the page or not. I have solved the rendering part, however I would like to optimize the fetching also.

Is there any way I can retrieve a smaller number of records, instead of the whole array which I parse afterwards?

I have found various answers where it was explained how to parse the response, but what I would like to to get a smaller response directly.

Comment: Ask API creator, we don't know this.

Comment: @BWA the API is a JSON file

Comment: if API has params for set which records you want set it, if not so there is no way

Answer (score 0):

As [BWA] mentioned in the comments, you can use the parameters available in the URL to fetch only a subset of records from a JSON. One commonly used name for that parameter is "limit" (see the documentation of an API you are using to know what that param is called if there is any).

Here's an example of retrieving only the initial 5 records from a JSON:

```
fetch('your_json_url?limit=5')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            // Process the retrieved data here
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle any errors that occur during the fetch request
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```